# Java Memory Model и happens-before

Tags: java, многопоточность, jvm

Добрый день. Есть небольшой вопрос по JMM. Я знаю как работает  happens-before, но не могу понять один момент. Вот код:

```
private static int x = 0;
private static volatile boolean flag = false;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

  new Thread(() -> {
      x = 10;
      while (!flag) ;
      System.out.println(x);
  }).start();

  x = 5;
  flag = true;
}
```

Какое значение должно принять X? Если какое-то правило чтобы определить это?

Comment: Любое из предложенных. Порядок присвоений 5 и 10 не определен, он может быть любым, порожденный тред может начать работу раньше `x = 5` и наоборот. Насколько понимаю, happens-before в данном случае распространяется только на `flag`, поэтому два разных треда могут существовать с разными значениями..

Comment: Да, я тоже думаю, что может быть либо 5 либо 10. 
НО если взять теорию JMM то как раз прочтение переменной flag в потоке 2(не main) означает, что транзитивное замыкание и  получается порядок становится полным!, то есть: 
1)  x = 5;
2)  flag = true;
3)  while (!flag)
4)  System.out.println(x);
Но вот как к этому порядку относится  x = 10; понять не могу, ведь внутри потока тоже порядок полный. Получается 2 полных порядка сливаются как-то?

Comment: прочтение переменной flag влияет только на видимость переменной flag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если изобразить потоки выполнения в вашем коде, мы получим такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Main thread - это основной поток вашей программы, Thread1 - поток, который вы явно создаете.

Запись и чтение волатильной переменной `flag` действительно создают отношение Happens-Before (*E → B* на диаграмме). Таким образом по отношению к вызову `System.out.println(x);` у нас есть два потока выполнения, для каждого из которых гарантируется порядок выполнения: *A → B → C* и *D → E → B → C*. Запись в переменную `x` произойдет гарантированно раньше ее чтения.

Но вот инструкции записи в переменную `x` (*A* и *D*) находятся в состоянии *гонки* (race condition) и их порядок выполнения друг относительно друга не определен. В итоге то, что мы видим на диаграмме никак нельзя назвать полным порядком. JVM вполне может выполнить инструкции следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Запись в переменную x произойдет гарантированно раньше ее чтения." данное предложение читается как будто один поток будет приостановлен пока второй не установит новое знание - но это не так.

Comment: @MikhailovValentine а тут без разницы, какой поток установит значение первым, все равно чтение произойдет после обоих записей

Comment: @Etki, да все верно, хотел указать на другое выполнение D → E → B → C не обязательно будет иметь место т.к. возможно что сначала произойдет   D → E а потом A → B → C и в таком случае диаграмма будет иметь другой вид.

Comment: @MikhailovValentine да все так же. Стрелка между двумя тредами просто показывает, что операция B обязана произойти после операции А. Порядок остальных операций между тредами не определен, эту диаграмма вполне читается как D-E-A-B-C.

Comment: @Etki, спасибо за апологетику. все именно так

Comment: @Etki, да пожалуй Вы правы придираюсь!

Answer (score 2):

Мы не знаем какое значение увидит инструкция `System.out.println(x);` по нескольким причинам:

- Поток может прочитать значение, установленное в нем (независимо было
  ли оно установлено раньше или позже другого потока) или значение,
  установленное в другом потоке. В виду того что гарантии на то, какое
  значение прочитает поток не даются.
- В виду того, что невозможно определить время выполнения инструкции в
  различных поток относительно других потоков - неизвестно в какой
  момент потоки выполнят инструкции `x = 10` и `flag = true`
  относительно друг друга.

Относительно *happens-before* происходящего с `volatile` переменной.
В данном случае если чтение `volatile` переменной происходит после записи ее переменной, то операция чтения **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** будет видеть "новые" данные. В данном случае нам это говорит лишь о том, что поток который находится в цикле выйдет из него, как только будет выполнена инструкция `flag = true`. Но опять же о том, когда будет выполнена инструкция `flag = true` нам неизвестно, она может быть выполнена как до, так и после чтения (одного или нескольких) значения из `volatile` переменной в порожденном потоке.

Необходимо отметить, что отношение, изображенное на картинке в ответе Nofate не должно трактоваться, как обязательный порядок индукцией или блокировка читателя до момента пока не будет установлено значение `volatile` переменной.

> “Запись в переменную x произойдет гарантированно раньше ее чтения.”

Поток просто будет находится в бесконечном цикле до момента выполнения `flag = true`.